Is the center of a graph a vertex in a path with lenght the diameter of the graph?
I have been doing some examples of graphs in which I've tried to find their centers and it caught my attention these always lied on some path (not neccesariy all in the same) with lenght equal to the diameter of the graph, which for me made kind of sense because the center would like to cut the largest distances in half. However, I have not been able to come with a proof this is always the case nor find a counterexample.
Searching for related questions I came to see on trees this is the case but I really couldn't extend the result to general graphs.

The center is a node with the least maximum distance to any other node?

If so, the answer is yes and it is easy to prove, since the distance between any two nodes cannot be larger then the (maximum) sum of the distances of the center to two nodes

@Exodd yes what you say is true, but it's not what I try to show. As you state, it is true that a smallest path going from one vertex to another, will have lenght smaller than or equal to the diameter, so in particular this will hold for smallest paths containing the center. But what is needed, is to show there is a smallest path between two vertices, which contains the center and has lenght exactly the diameter of the graph.

I showed exactly what you said

Could you please tell me how do you get the equality?

Ok, I admit I was too fast.
It is indeed false.
I found this counterexample, I do not know if there is a smaller one.
Take 13 nodes:

$c$ the center
$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_6$ the first layer
$y_1, y_2, \dots, y_6$ the second layer

$c$ is connected to all nodes on the first layer.
$x_i$ and $y_i$ are connected for all $i$.
The $x_i$ form a clique, i.e. they are connected to each other
The $y_i$ form a cycle, i.e. $y_1 - y_2 - \dots - y_6 - y_1$.
$c$ is a center because the most distant nodes are $y_i$ at distance 2.
The diameter is 3, and the only couples of nodes at distance 3 are $y_1-y_{4}$, $y_2-y_5$, $y_3-y_6$. None of these paths of length 3 pass through $c$.

Thank you very much for your answer, I also added a post as an answer to what is the minimum counterexample possible, motivated by the graph you described.

This is not a counterexample to the stated question because the vertex $c$ lies on a path of length $3$, namely the path $cx_1y_1y_2$. The condition that the path be the shortest path between its endpoints  was added in a comment, but that makes it a different question.

@user14111 in the question the author says "the center would like to cut the largest distances in half" that already is an indicator of what it is specified in the comment.
P.s. If we forget this condition, then it is easily true just by looking at a balanced tree with the center as root

The counterexample shown by Exodd is correct and shows a pretty example of a graph in which there is a center which doesn't belong to any smallest path between two nodes with lenght equal to the diameter of the graph. I write this just as a complement to Exodd's answer, where I'll show we can find a conterexample with 5 nodes, which will in fact be the minimum possible.
In the following image the red node is a center of the graph. However, as can be seen, there doesn't exist a smallest path between two nodes which contains it and has also lenght 3 (the diameter of the graph). If anyone draws the graph proposed by Exodd, they will notice the basic building block for the center selected as a counterexample is precisely this graph.

We can also observe in the list of all possible connected graphs with less than 5 vertices, every center satisfyes the property. Thus 5 nodes is the minimum required for a counterexample.


Not a counterexample because there is a path of length $3$ (or length $4$ for that matter) which contains the red vertex. Your original question did not require the path to be the shortesr path between its endpoints. That condition was tacked on in a comment, changing the question.
